# X crashes immediately on login

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, xorg

The errors I get say there are problems loading the Nvidia kernel modules, but I tried purging the Nvidia drivers also with no success. Is there a way to completely restore Xorg configuration to default?

Comment: Yes, wipe the partition and reinstall from scratch.

Otherwise, you need to give us more info!

Comment: Let me know where I can find this info, and I'd be happy to provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that ended up working for me was completely reinstalling Ubuntu. Even then, though, I still got this same error. It wasn't until I wiped the ~/.config directory that I was finally able to log in. The cause of this problem remains a mystery.