# Will reinstalling ubuntu wipe /var/www?

Tags: installation, server

I have a testing server set up in /var/www, and a mySQL database somewhere, and I recently have been having problems where X won't load. The only [suggestion so far](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236800/x-crashes-immediately-on-login#comment294627_236800) is to reinstall. Normally, that wouldn't be a problem, since I have a different drive mapped to `/home`, but I'm scared that reinstalling will wipe `/var/www` and other directories where I have much-needed config files.

Comment: If you start by making a backup of those files what do you see  as a problem?

Comment: @Jon, would you mind sharing the partition table of the system

Comment: /home gets its own drive, but everything else is on one drive. So it's Drive 1: ~20 gig partition for system files, ~4 gig partition for swap, and Drive 2: one ~500 gig partition for /home. The next time I do this I should probably make /var/www its own partition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on how you partitioned your hard drive. But, if `/var` was not given its own partition, reinstalling Ubuntu will wipe `/var`.

Not only would you need to backup `/var/www`, but you would also need to backup `/var/lib/mysql`, where your MySQL database lives.

Comment: Excellent! This backup suggestion works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Ubuntu 18.04, a server install insists on wiping /var. This takes out /var/www (thats your website gone); /var/spool/mail (your emails are toast) and quite a bit else.

This is regardless of whether /var was on a different partition.

How do I know? Well, I just changed the MB on my aging server and lost the lot. Welcome to a day of restoring backups.